# Animate text color jQuery CSS hover disappears?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an issue when I make a button and have it change color when hovering over it works fine but when I first animate the color using jQuery then the hovering color doesn't work anymore but the active color when clicking still works, whats up with that?

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" class='button'>BUTTON</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
.button {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color:#808080;
  background-color:#808080;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.button:hover {
   color: #fff; 
}
.button:active {
   background-color:#3C3C3C;
   color: #000; 
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.button').animate({color:'#ccc' },1000);
```

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rydy96td/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `!important` to your hover as below:

```
.button:hover {
   color: #fff !important; 
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/rydy96td/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Its because, when you're using:

```
$('.button').animate({color:'#ccc' },1000);
```

It sets *inline CSS* to your `<a>` as:

```
<a style="color: rgb(204, 204, 204);" href="#" class="button">BUTTON</a>
```

and *inline CSS* has more preference over *external* or *internal CSS* so to override it you can do as *Guruprasad Rao* stated above OR you can do this:

```
.button[style]:hover {
   color: #FFF !important;
 }
```

the *[style]* selector will only work if your element has *inline CSS* only.